# Probability of event in Monte Carlo roulette wheel problem

Tags: probability

> A Monte Carlo roulette wheel has $18$ red numbers, $18$ black numbers
>   and one green number. The probability of the ball NOT landing on a
>   black number is ?

**My work** :

$18+18=36$

$\frac{18}{36}$ = the probability of not landing on a black number.

---

Is this the correct way to solve the question and if not how would I solve this?

Comment: There are 19 not black numbers and 37 total numbers.

Comment: so the answer is 19/37 of the ball NOT landing on a black number?

Comment: simply use (**total probablity** - **the probability of  landing on a black number**)

Answer (score 3):

As long as all outcomes have an equal chance of happening, the probability of an event can be understood as the number of successful outcomes divided by the total possible outcomes:

$P(black) = \frac{\# black\ numbers}{\# total\ numbers}$

$P(not\ black) = \frac{\# not\ black\ numbers}{\# total\ numbers}.$

To answer the question, we assume it's a fair roulette wheel. The second equation above is appropriate to use. Your attempt miscounted both the not black numbers and the total numbers.

---

Alternatively, as mentioned by @statistics, you can use the following equation:

$$P(black) + P(not\ black) = 1$$

Since all outcomes are either black or not black but not both, we call these outcomes *complements*. Together, they represent every possible outcome. The sum of their probabilities must be one.